# Query using ObjectId in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, reference

I have a notes collection as:

```
{
    note: {
            type: String,
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
}
```

where "createdBy" contains _id of a user from users collection.
First Question: Should I define it as String or ObjectId?

Second Question:
While querying the data as `db.users.find({ createdBy: ObjectId(userid) },'notes')`. Is it a O(1) operation?
Or, do I have to create an index for that to be 0(1)?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your user collection is using `ObjectId` then you would better also use `ObjectId` in notes collection since you may want to `$lookup` them.
2. Only `_id` field would create index in the begging of collection. You need to create index for `createdBy` since you want O(1) operation.